# How to not have a tab or window open up when serving my Ionic Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app in Ionic using Cordova. I want to start the serve task `ionic cordova run browser` and not have a new tab open up everytime. Ideally I would already have `http://localhost:8000/index.html` opened and would like to reload it.

Comment: Why would you want to run it without having it open up in a new tab/window?

Comment: Because I always have the tab open and I just want to refresh it.

Answer (score 2):

That's just part of the command `cordova run browser`. You'll probably want to use [live-reloading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-browsersync) for the browser and then you'll use the command `cordova run -- --live-reload`.

Personally for me, I just use Python's `python3 -m http.server` to serve up my www folder, go to my IP address in my browser (port 8000 is where it will put it), and just refresh the page whenever I need to update. You can download python [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: My solution was creating a new Ionic 4 project and migrating the old code component by component. It serves with `ng serve` now and it works as I'm used to. Plus I get all the advantages of upgrading.